# Subuser cannot login to Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I created a sub-user and try to login in sendgrid it will throw an error message Your username or password is invalid. How to log in the sub-user in sendgrid?

Answer (score 1):

Sub-user's username is not necessarily an email address.
You need to look at the URL to find the correct username.

Comment: Specifically, I was able to sign in to a Subuser account by using the account User Name and contact password and NOT the email address